No error message provided by the last invocation of @RetryingTest
I have a test like this (language is Kotlin):
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyTest {
    private var i: Int = 0

    @RetryingTest(3)
    fun go() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, 2, "wow ${++i}")
    }
}

All 3 invocations of this test fail and the last invocation leaves the following trace:
org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: wow 1 ==>


    at org.junitpioneer.jupiter.RetryingTestExtension$FailedTestRetrier.failed(RetryingTestExtension.java:161)
    at org.junitpioneer.jupiter.RetryingTestExtension.handleTestExecutionException(RetryingTestExtension.java:64)
Caused by: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: wow 1 ==> expected: <1> but was: <2>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:563)
    at MyTest.go(MyTest.kt:114)
    ... 17 more


org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: wow 2 ==>


    at org.junitpioneer.jupiter.RetryingTestExtension$FailedTestRetrier.failed(RetryingTestExtension.java:161)
    at org.junitpioneer.jupiter.RetryingTestExtension.handleTestExecutionException(RetryingTestExtension.java:64)
Caused by: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: wow 2 ==> expected: <1> but was: <2>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:563)
    at MyTest.go(MyTest.kt:114)
    ... 17 more


org.opentest4j.MultipleFailuresError: Test execution #3 (of up to 3 with at least 1 successes) failed ~> test fails - see cause for details (2 failures)
    org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: wow 1 ==> expected: <1> but was: <2>
Test execution #1 (of up to 3) failed ~> will retry in 0 ms...
    org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: wow 2 ==> expected: <1> but was: <2>
Test execution #2 (of up to 3) failed ~> will retry in 0 ms...

    at org.junitpioneer.jupiter.RetryingTestExtension$FailedTestRetrier.failed(RetryingTestExtension.java:167)
    at org.junitpioneer.jupiter.RetryingTestExtension.handleTestExecutionException(RetryingTestExtension.java:64)

As you can see, there's no wow 3 message printed anywhere in the logs.
How can I see the error produced by the last invocation?

I tried your test like this.

@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyTest {
    private var i: Int = 0

    @RepeatedTest(3)
    fun go() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, 2, "wow ${++i}")
    }
}

then I got this log.
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: wow 1 ==> 
Expected :1
Actual   :2
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:563)
    at stackoverflow.MyTest.go(MyTest.kt:13)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:104)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:711)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: wow 2 ==> 
Expected :1
Actual   :2
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:563)
    at stackoverflow.MyTest.go(MyTest.kt:13)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:104)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:711)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)


org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: wow 3 ==> 
Expected :1
Actual   :2
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:563)
    at stackoverflow.MyTest.go(MyTest.kt:13)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:108)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:711)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)


how about using @RepeatedTest instead of @RetryingTest ?

I actually need retrying, not repeated one.
@RepeatedTest will execute all 3 times, whereas @RetryingTest executes once unless there's an error.
